# Вывести элементы массива целых чисел в порядке возрастания их числа делителей

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Не удается реализовать алгоритм нахождения числа делителей у массива,прошу помощи в этом деле.@Harry , вы любите отвечать на мои вопросы, так что милости прошу))).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


void sort()//функция нахождения числа делителей и сортировки    
{

}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    int m;
    m = 0;
    printf("a[n],n=...\n");//число элементов в массиве
    scanf("%i", &n);
    int a[n];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)//задание значений каждого из элементов
    {
        printf("number %i=", i);
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
    }
    sort(a, n);//выполнение функции по сортировке элементов массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)/*вывод элементов в порядке возрастания их 
                                                                числа делителей*/
    {
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*Однако мне удалось реализовать алгоритм поиска делителей отдельного числа*/

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int i;
    int m;
    m = 0;
    printf("enter x...");
    scanf("%i", &x);//прием значения переменной с клавиатуры
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)/*цикл для вычисления числа делителей 
                 заданной переменной*/
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
            m++;
    }
    printf("m=%i", m);//вывод числа делителей
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ой, перед рабочим днем совершенно нет времени, на завтра надо кучу дел подготовить... А тут надо просто получить количество делителей (факторизация на простые числа и произведение увеличенных на 1 их степеней дает количество делителей с 1 и самим числом включительно), ну, а дальше - просто сортировка...

Comment: @Harry я ,наверное, тупой , поскольку , понимая алгоритм, все равно не могу записать его в виде кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте я не буду писать сложный алгоритм, а напишу простой, хоть и не самый эффективный, зато быстро пишется :)...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void calculateDivisors(pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>& p)
{
    unsigned int n = p.first, d = 0, i;
    for(i = 1; i*i < n; ++i)
        if (n%i == 0) d+=2;

    if (i*i == n) ++d;   // если число - квадрат
    p.second = d;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>> v;
    // Чтение чисел
    cout << "Enter values, negative to stop\n";
    for(int i = 1, n;;++i)
    {
        cout << "#" << i << ": ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 0) break;
        v.emplace_back(n,0);
    }

    // Вычисление количества делителей во ворое поле пары
    for(auto& p: v)
        calculateDivisors(p);

    // Сортировка по числу делителей
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),
         [](auto a, auto b) { return a.second < b.second; });

    // Вывод чисел и количества делителей
    for(auto p: v)
        cout << setw(6) << p.first << "   "
            << setw(3) << p.second << endl;
}
```

На C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int calculateDivisors(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int d = 0, i;
    for(i = 1; i*i < n; ++i)
        if (n%i == 0) d+=2;

    if (i*i == n) ++d;   // если число - квадрат
    return d;
}

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned int d;
} pair;

// Функция сравнения для сортировки - по делителям, потом по числам
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    pair * p = (pair*)a;
    pair * q = (pair*)b;
    int res = (q->d < p->d) - (p->d < q->d);
    if (res) return res;
    return (q->n < p->n) - (p->n < q->n);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int n;
    printf("Count of numbers: ");
    scanf("%u",&n);
    pair * p = malloc(n*sizeof(pair));
    // Чтение чисел
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int x;
        printf("Value #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%u",&x);
        p[i].n = x;
        p[i].d = calculateDivisors(x);
    }

    // Сортировка по числу делителей
    qsort(p,n,sizeof(pair),comp);

    // Вывод чисел и количества делителей
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%6u   %3u\n",p[i].n, p[i].d);
}
```

Comment: лучше бы на си , а то на c++ синтаксис другой немного, плохо понимаю

Comment: Блин... не обратил внимания на язык... Но это уже завтра...

Comment: ок, но все равно спасибо, я попробую еще на си с c++ "перевести"

Comment: Написал. Только давайте больше на меня в приготовлении домашек не рассчитывать? :)

Comment: Да она не на оценку даже,прост решить долго не мог, поэтому и обратился